# Android Studio CardView error: could not be instantiated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-cardview

I get this error whenever I put a CardView in my activity_main.xml.

The following classes could not be instantiated:

- `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

I've added this to the build.gradle :

```
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    //CardView
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    //RecyclerView
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
```

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >



    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context="com.example.ivanp.meteostanica.TvrdjavaFragment"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/bubanj"
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_margin="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using same version of your appcompat-v7.

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `appcompat` version.

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0
```

> And also add if you haven't added design support.

```
com.android.support:design:25.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The theme was not compatible. I started a new project with the default theme and just added this to the build.gradle.

```
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1' //CardView
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'//RecyclerView
```

After that I just added the CardView in Design Mode and it worked, no errors.

Answer (score 0):

In case its about missing styles add `style="@style/CardView"` to your CardView.