# Why the CardView is being displayed but I am not seeing the items of it?

Tags: android, android-layout

Here are XML snapshots:

1.
[image: image 1]

2.[image: image 2]

3.[image: image 3]

4.[image]

5.[image]

Comment: Copy and paste your code into the question.. It's not a good approach to post pictures of your code...

Comment: I am new here and on doing that it says format it, how can i do that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: For that much code you will have to provide some elaborate prose explanation, too. Or shrink your [mre].

Comment: Six questions, two answers, eight months, 40+ reputation. What exactly do you mean by "new"? Nevertheless, here is info to help you familiarise: [tour], [ask], https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: @Yunnosch Totally understandable. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Duh. Layout is most probably fine (as I can judge from these screenshots) the problem can be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40264125/android-studio-cardview-error-could-not-be-instantiated

Comment: Yunnosch,I like you giving much details, it will be lovely if you would have searched that when I started posting as at that time, I became active,

Comment: Sorry Vaibhav, I do not understand what you mean. (By the way, to address a comment to a user, e.g. me, please use the syntax with an @ character. E.g. @Yunnosch.)

Comment: @Yunnosch,so which part of it you did not understand

Comment: "it will be lovely" why future?  "I became active" What does that mean? Why is it a reason for the first part? What did I search? So basically I did not understand anything after "I like you giving much details".

Answer (score 0):

Update the elevation of your items in the xml,

put `android:elevation="2dp"` on the framelayout 
and to avoid the shadow it brings, add `android:outlineProvider="none"`

Comment: It gives same result